# how to reshape a tensor e.g [?,64,?,?] to [?,?,?,64]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an input with:

```
<tf.Tensor 'conv1/conv1_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 64, ?, ?) dtype=float32>
```

and I want to change this shape=(?, 64, ?, ?) to shape=(?, ?, ?, 64). how to do it?

Comment: Can you change `?` to `A`, `B`, and `C` so we know what dimensions you want in which position?

Comment: I wan to switch from B to D , D to C, C to B

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) with `perm` parameter which will permute the dimensions:

```
tf.transpose(your_tensor, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])
```

e.g.

```
>>> t = tf.random.normal(shape=(5, 64, 3, 9))

>>> tf.transpose(t, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1]).shape

TensorShape([5, 3, 9, 64])
```

Comment: I have tried the above method but its not working my output remains unchange:
`input = <tf.Tensor 'conv1/conv1_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 64, ?, ?) dtype=float32>`

Comment: @ayazumer You need to set the result back: `your_tensor = tf.transpose(your_tensor, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])`. Does that help?

Comment: still not working after executing the above command it remains unchanged
`(Pdb) a=tf.transpose(input, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1]).shape
input = <tf.Tensor 'conv1/conv1_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 64, ?, ?) dtype=float32>`

Comment: `input = tf.transpose(input, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])` can you try this (no .shape at the end, and assigning the result back to `input`.) @ayazumer

Comment: @ayazumer Glad to be of help! If you wish, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved.